# Derby won't let me re-create a data base

Tags: glassfish-3, derby

I'm developing a JSF/JPA application under Glassfish which uses Derby (JavaDB) as it's default data base.  It turns out the "DROP AND CREATE" policy of the Persistence Unit doesn't work reliably, so i have taken to deleting the data base and then re-creating it it when I change the schema.

Or at least I am trying to.  If I delete the data base, it won't let me create a "new" data base with the same time as the deleted one.   Nor will it let me open the old one.

My work around for now is just create a data base with a new name and use that (have to edit the glassfish resources xml file each time) but I would like to know what is going on.  Anybody else have this problem and/or know how to fix it?

Comment: Can you provide more details? How are you deleting and re-creating the database? Are you issuing 'drop table' statements? Or are you doing something external to Java? What do you mean 'it won't let you create a new database'? What is 'it'? Do you get an error? What line of code gets the error? What exception or error message do you get? What does the derby.log say?

Comment: @BryanPendleton I am using the Netbeans 7.2 user interface.  On the Services window you can right-click on DataBases->JavaDB and there is a popup menu that provides Create/Delete service.   I have no idea what commands it actually issues to the server.

Comment: My guess is that some previous run of your application still has the database open, and so the create/delete service operation is actually failing. But to properly diagnose this you're going to need to get a lot more comfortable with what Netbeans is doing, and how Derby works. Alternatively, depending on your platform (Windows?) you could use tools such as Process Explorer that will help you explore which applications have which files open, to see if you can track down whether some other copy of Derby still has the database open.

Comment: @BryanPendleton I think you're right.  It seems that my Glassfish server is maintaining a connection to the data base.  Netbeans won't stop the server unless it exits itself or it is asked to.   In those cases I can delete and re-create the data base, although I wonder why it allows me to delete it if someone is using it.   Thanks for the clue if you want to write it up as an answer I'll check it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I understand what the pathology of this problem is, but I have a work-around.  It would be good someone could enter a bug-report to the Netbeans community or give me a link to do it.

The problem is created on a MacOS version of NetBeans 7.2, with the GlassFish 3.1 server under its management.   When you start the server to run your app, it automatically starts Derby (the Java DB) with it.  However when you stop the GlassFish server or even exit Netbeans, the Derby installation stays running.

When you start NetBeans & GlassFish again, you will note that when it attempts to start the Derby server it will complain that port 1527 is already in use.  Normally this is not a problem, since the application will continue to run and communicate to the previously-started Derby process via the port it is holding open.  However I suspect that the communications path used by the Netbeans menu system to delete and create a data base does NOT use this data path, and consequently attempts to do a delete/create operation on a data structure that is held open by a process with which it is not communicating.  Hence the lock up and failure.

The work around is to kill the Derby process in the background, then do the Delete/Create operation, and it works fine.   On MacOS or Linux, open a command window and do a

```
ps axe | grep -i derby
```

and you will find a java JVM running Derby.  Just copy the process ID and do

```
kill <pid>
```

(the -9 seems not to be necessary) and do the ps command again and you should see the process is gone.  Derby will be started by Netbeans the next time it is needed.